# Phonegap onscroll not working until scroll stops

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, scroll

I'm developing an ios app using phonegap and jquery mobile. I have a list in my application that can scroll and I use

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; overflow : scroll;
```

as for scrolling to feel like native. My problem is that onscroll event does not triggered until scroll stops. It is triggered just when your finger is on top of the screen ( in touchmove state) and after that it does not triggered until it stops.  I know about some other scroll plugins like iscroll , but I don't want to use them , because they are too buggy. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: where are you binding the scroll event?? use ("html, body") and see if there is any diffrence

Comment: I have put -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; around my content (.ui-content class in jquery mobile). I used ("html,body") and onscroll is not called at all.

Answer (score 1):

You will find your answer here:
http://developer.telerik.com/featured/scroll-event-change-ios-8-big-deal/

Comment: Yes, you should add a quote too: Although Apple implemented this change in iOS Safari, as well as its new WKWebView control, it did not change the scroll behavior in its old UIWebView control. And because of a major bug in the replacement WKWebView control, the Cordova team cannot upgrade to WKWebView yet.