# Cordova Momentum Scrolling on iOS Overflow Elements

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

Listening to scroll events in Safari iOS browser triggers the console message every time, even on the momentum, but in the cordova built app that triggers only when the scroll has stopped.

```
el-with-webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch.on('scroll', function()
{ i++; console.log('Scroll: ' + i); }

);
```

GIF on the cordova app: http://recordit.co/I3eiucGAWd

GIF in Safari browser (same emulator): http://recordit.co/QhBNcccjPj

This happens on the real device too.

This looks like a bug to me, but maybe somebody knows a quick hack/fix
Bug posted here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9655

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugin that helps (but needs testing): http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/wkwebview

As mentioned in this question: [Phonegap onscroll not working untill scroll stops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27468736/phonegap-onscroll-not-working-untill-scroll-stops) and read in this article: http://developer.telerik.com/featured/scroll-event-change-ios-8-big-deal/

> Although Apple implemented this change in iOS Safari, as well as its
>   new WKWebView control, it did not change the scroll behavior in its
>   old UIWebView control. And because of a major bug in the replacement
>   WKWebView control, the Cordova team cannot upgrade to WKWebView yet.
>
> This means that at the moment Cordova apps running on iOS 8 continue
>   to pause JavaScript execution, and will continue to until Cordova can
>   upgrade. And this doesn’t just affect Cordova apps. Any iOS app that
>   uses web views — including Facebook, Twitter, and Chrome for iOS —
>   will get the old behavior until they upgrade their apps to WKWebView.
>   So yes, that means you could get different behavior opening the same
>   URL from different iOS apps depending on which API they use
>   internally.