# Which event to listen to during inertia/momentum scroll on Cordova iOS w/ React

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, reactjs, phonegap

I have a React app running on iOS through cordova/phonegap.

In one component, I have a toolbar that sticks to the top of the screen once you scroll past it:

```
<div id="content">Some stuff in here</div>
<div id="tool-bar">
    <div class="tool">Tool 1</div>
    <div class="tool">Tool 2</div>
</div>
<div id="some-stuff-below-toolbar">Stuff</div>
```

You get the picture.

Whenever the user scrolls, the Y position is calculated, and if it's below the offset, the tool bar gets a class 'sticky' and CSS to fix it to the top:

ReactJS:

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', this.updateScrollY);
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', this.updateScrollY);
}

updateScrollY() {
    const current_y = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    this.setState({...this.state, current_y});
}

render() {
    let classNames = '';
    if(this.state.current_y >= this.state.offset) {
        classNames = 'sticky';
    }

    return(...some JSX...
        <div id='tool-bar' className={classNames}> ... etc more JSX);  
}
```

CSS:

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Now, this all works in Chrome/Safari, but on iOS/Cordova, the scroll event is not fired during momentum scrolling. So, if a user scrolls past the offset limit whilst holding the screen, fine, because the `touchmove` event keeps firing. However, if the user scrolls for a bit, releases the screen, and the momentum / inertia scrolling makes the view scroll past the offset, nothing happens until the scroll ends (because then the `scroll` event is fired).

**Question:**

> Is there a separate event I can listen for, or is there a Cordova
>   setting that makes javascript execute during inertia/momentum
>   scrolling?

---

**setInterval()**

I've also tried setting an interval on touchend (the user stopped scrolling/touching) and removing it later, but it seems that during momentum/inertia scrolling, no javascript is ran at all: the setInterval doesn't execute during that time.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this one?

Comment: [Found it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32567113/cordova-momentum-scrolling-on-ios-overflow-elements)