# Scroll events during momentum scrolling in Cordova for IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, scroll, momentum

Variations of this question have been asked before (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44798796/which-event-to-listen-to-during-inertia-momentum-scroll-on-cordova-ios-w-react) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32567113/cordova-momentum-scrolling-on-ios-overflow-elements)), but with no conclusive answers yet.

Is there a way to get scroll events to trigger (and use these listeners to update the DOM) during the momentum/inertia/deceleration part of the scroll in a Cordova application built for IOS?

[This article](https://dzone.com/articles/why-scroll-event-change-ios-8) from 5.5 years ago outlines the issue, but that was *5.5 years ago*. Surely there must be a work around right? Right??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the best way to solve this problem is to install Apache's `wkwebview` plugin:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine

Adding that to my project caused the `('scroll')` listener to fire events even during momentum scrolling